# ASP.NET Grid View Not Displaying

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have changed a Grid View from UltraWebGid to ASP.NET Grid View.

The code for ASP.NET Grid View is like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLicenseMaintainHistory" runat="server" CssClass="gridScroll" >
    <asp:GridView ID="gridLicenseMaintainHistory" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        EmptyDataText="No Records Found" EnableViewState="True" Width="99%" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkButtonLicenseMaintainHistory" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("licensemaintain_hst_key")%>' Text="Select"
                        OnClick="lnkLicenseMaintainHistory_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="6%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="License Type" DataField="license_info" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="License ID" DataField="license_id" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Issued Date" DataField="issued_dttm" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn" HtmlEncode="False">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Effective Beg Date" DataField="effective_begin_dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn" HtmlEncode="False" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Effective End Date" DataField="effective_end_dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn" HtmlEncode="False" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="license_status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Update By" DataField="updated_by" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Updated Date" DataField="updated_dttm" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn" HtmlEncode="False" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Record Type" DataField="record_type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filterColumn">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

But when I go to my application the Grid View doesn't show up. What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't Show? Is there an error? Does it say 'No Records Found'?

Comment: There is no error and it also doesn't say "No Records Found".

Comment: Ok. So it doesn't sound at least like the DataSource is being set, or if it is, is DataBind() being run? Do you have code-behind for this?

Comment: Did you bind it to a datasource?

Comment: After formatting your text I have noticed you are missing the closing tag for <asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing tag for `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">`. Had you formatted your markup correctly, you would've noticed that.